# Automated Test With Image Comparison

Tags: automated-testing, c#

I have a WPF application and I have a custom object (the output) with images and text. I need to check if the output has a correct format. I tried with Coded UI but, because the element is a custom object, I can't compare its properties.

Which is the best tool to compare visual objects? I also need it to be able to automate the test.

Thanks.

Comment: This is amazing concept and have been searching more details in image comparison. Do you have any resources for the same? I would like to learn more on image comparison technique. Please share any links that would be really appreciable.

Comment: I ended up using snapshots and snapshots verifiers. I used the link in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TestApi](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=testapi) (a .NET library) offers visual comparison and is pretty easy to get working. I flirted with the idea of integrating it with our project but I'm still not convinced that automated visual verification testing is suitable for long term regression testing. But if I had to do it then I'd start with TestApi. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160210015952/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2009/04/20/9557563.aspx) is the tutorial for comparing images.

Comment: Yeah, this was the one I ended up using. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I use TestComplete in order to test images. From the tool itself I store images (several formats supported) then, when I run my coded tests I compare the actual image on the running application (identified by object ID or by paths) with the stored image (it compares bit a bit). It works fine.

TestComplete supports WPF applications as well.

http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools/testcomplete-integrations/wpf-application-support/

Cons: It's a comercial tool.

Comment: It's a shame it is comercial.. Does it allow automatation of test?

Comment: Yes. It also supports C# scripting language as a base programming language for building your test cases and flows. As I mentioned before it is a comercial tool with hight prices... There are other tools which also compares images at a run time but they are comercial as well. So it's only advisable for enterprise projects.

Comment: A little more info on TestComplete - it's actually cheaper than most of the other big box commercial tools especially if you need to use multiple systems to execute your tests because SmartBear offers a lightweight execution application at a much lower cost. I'm not affiliated, just used the product for years.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools) tools, a lot of them are open sourced, I heard that [sikuli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikuli) does the job regarding images, but never tried it.
You can also take a screenshot of the screen and compare it to a saved one...